# How do I create this following sequence?

Tags: r, dataframe

Use: seq(),rep()and possibly other commonly-used operators/functions,but NOT c()or any explicit loops to create the following sequences (compound expres-sions are allowed).

I have this sequence I wanted to create:

```
2.5 5.5 9.5 14.5 20.5 27.5 35.5
```

I know the increment is cumsum(3:8) but how do I put this into rep(seq(2.5, 35.5))? I tried:

```
rep(seq(2.5, 35.5, cumsum(3:8)))
```

but it gives me error. How do I do this? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need

```
c(2.5, 2.5 + cumsum(3:8))
[1]  2.5  5.5  9.5 14.5 20.5 27.5 35.5
```

or slightly more compact

```
2.5 + c(0, cumsum(3:8))
[1]  2.5  5.5  9.5 14.5 20.5 27.5 35.5
```

---

If we don't want any `c`, why not create a 0 vector and fill it

```
out <- numeric(7) 
# or use rep
out <- rep(0, 7)
out[1] <- 2.5
out[-1] <- 2.5 + cumsum(3:8)
out
[1]  2.5  5.5  9.5 14.5 20.5 27.5 35.5
```

Or use `replace`

```
replace(rep(2.5, 7), -1, 2.5 + cumsum(3:8))
[1]  2.5  5.5  9.5 14.5 20.5 27.5 35.5
```

Or as @user20650 mentioned

```
rep(2.5, 7) + unlist(list(0, cumsum(seq(3, 8))))
[1]  2.5  5.5  9.5 14.5 20.5 27.5 35.5
```

Or use `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
lag(2.5 + cumsum(3:9),  default = 2.5)
[1]  2.5  5.5  9.5 14.5 20.5 27.5 35.5
```

Comment: I can't use c(). Is there a way without using the c()?

Comment: @JesseLingLing the `3:8` is just `seq(3, 8)`

Comment: @JesseLingLing can you use `cumsum` as I found it in your post

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? Do you mean 2.5 + rep(seq(0, cumsum(3:8))) ?

Comment: @JesseLingLing I meant you are using `cumsum` in the post, but your description says `rep` and seq

Comment: Oh, I can use cumsum but not c().

Comment: Is there a way by just using rep(), seq() and cumsum()? Or just rep() and seq()?

Comment: @JesseLingLing even within `rep`, you may need a `c(`,  I don't understand what kindof rules these are

Comment: The question specifically stated that I can't use c() or any explicit loops. Apparently just by  using rep(), seq() and maybe with cumsum is enough for this question. But I don't know how.

Comment: @JesseLingLing what I meant is that why would somebody wants to do this without any `c`.  It doesn't make sense

Comment: @JesseLingLing updated with `rep` and not without c

Comment: @JesseLingLing Does it ban `replace` too.  I updated with `replace`

Comment: @akrun; sub `unlist(list` for `c` ;p

Comment: @user20650 not sure if they permit `list/unlist` as well :=)

Comment: @akrun yup the replace one should work. Thank you so much! Is there a way that you could explain what does the replace do here? Thanks

Comment: @JesseLingLing the `list` argument in `replace` can take either logical or numeric index.  With `-1`, it is suggesting to replace other other positions except 1

Comment: How about just `cumsum(2:8) + .5`.

Comment: @27ϕ9 Thanks, but that is not using `rep`

Comment: `n = 1:7; -0.5 + (n+1)*(n+2)/2 `